# How to make a module depend from another in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have 2 modules, one that creates an RDS cluster and one that creates an EC2 instance. I call both modules in my main file:

```
module "instance" {
  source = "../instance"
  rds_endpoint    = module.databases.rds_cluster_endpoint

}

module "databases" {
  source      = "../databases"
}
```

In the "instance" module, I have a null resource that basically grabs a dump.sql file and tries to import mysql data into the RDS cluster. the problem is that for some reason, the null resource runs before the RDS instance is completed (and of course fails, because the endpoint is not ready yet). I thought that by defining an output in the "databases" module with the cluster endpoint would create an implicit dependency, so I was expecting the databases modules to complete first, because I am referencing it in the instance module, but this doesn't seem to be the case.
Apparently the explicit `depends_on` for modules is implemented in terraform 0.13, but it's in beta, and we just can't move the entire infrastructure to 0.13 just because of this. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: if you mention one resource into another, terraform creates dependency automatically. So you shouldn't care about it.Here is the post with example https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-create-aws-rds-cluster-with-imported-sql-dump-from-s3-using-terraform/

Answer (score 2):

I use similar pattern to create dependency among modules and it works ok. Not sure why is it not working in this case may be because of null resource. You may try importing the sql file from `s3`. See the docs [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#s3-import-options):

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
  s3_import {
    source_engine         = "mysql"
    source_engine_version = "5.6"
    bucket_name           = "mybucket"
    bucket_prefix         = "backups"
    ingestion_role        = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/role-xtrabackup-rds-restore"
  }
}
```

Comment: We did explore this option, but this is locked to use the xtrabackup from percona. We are looking to use imports using something everybody in the team is familiar, and mysqldump is what everybody uses, which is not supported with this importing method

Comment: @SimonErnestoCardenasZarate Not a good solution but for testing purposes you may try this. Try adding sleep 600 in the startup/user data script of your instance.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a value to the variable `rds_endpoint` using a reference to `module.databases.rds_cluster_endpoint`, which declares a dependency from the `variable "rds_endpoint"` in the "instance" to the `output "rds_cluster_endpoint"` in the "databases" module.

Because of the effect of transitive dependencies, this means that anything in the "instance" module that refers to `var.rds_endpoint` will effectively depend on everything that the `output "rds_cluster_endpoint"` block in the "databases" module depends on. Conversely though, a dependency on `var.rds_endpoint` *only* implies depending on exactly what `output "rds_cluster_endpoint"` depends on; nothing else in the "databases" module will be a dependency unless you declare that to be true.

Notice that the module *itself* is not a dependency node: each input variable and output value is a *separate* dependency node, which allows Terraform to optimize its work by beginning actions in a module as the specific input variables *it* depends on are ready, rather than waiting until *all* of the input variables are ready. However, that does mean you need to be mindful of what each individual output value depends on and which input variables each resource in a module depends on.

If you have objects in your configuration that represent [hidden dependencies](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#resource-dependencies) -- that is, where a particular ordering is required even though there's no reference-based relationship -- you can use the `depends_on` argument either in the `output "rds_cluster_endpoint"` block or in the resources that ultimately depend on it (or, in some cases, both!) to add additional dependency relationships to the graph.

Since you didn't share the configuration for the two modules themselves I can't show a specific example, but here's a general example of using `depends_on` in the output block to refer to an additional object that the `value` expression doesn't naturally depend on:

```
output "rds_cluster_endpoint" {
  value = aws_db_instance.db.endpoint

  # The instance role must also be active before
  # this instance can be used, to avoid
  # authorization errors.
  depends_on = [aws_db_instance_role_association.main]
}
```

I've used a `aws_db_instance_role_association` object here just because this is a typical example of a "hidden dependency": due to the design of these objects, Terraform by default understands the role association as depending on the instance rather than the other way around (because the instance must be created first), but if the downstream users of this database instance expect to be able to use the S3 integration then the role association being assigned is an important part of the functionality this module is offering and so any object that depends on the `rds_cluster_endpoint` should depend on the role association too. You may have a different hidden dependency to model rather than this one, but the same pattern would apply.

The other side of this is making sure that everything in the "instance" module which relies on the RDS instance depends on the same objects that output depends on. This problem arises less often because objects in your "instance" module that need the RDS instance would typically already refer to `var.rds_endpoint` as part of their configuration. However, in unusual cases where that isn't true for some reason, you can add an explicit dependency on the variable from any resource that must wait for the instance to be ready but yet doesn't refer to `var.rds_endpoint` for some reason:

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  # if the arguments of this resource don't
  # already make use of var.rds_endpoint but
  # yet this resource must still wait until
  # the RDS instance is ready for some reason,
  # you can mark that explicitly:
  depends_on = [var.rds_endpoint]
}
```

Even though Terraform 0.13 does have module-level `depends_on`, it's still better to model the dependencies at a higher level of detail like I've shown above where possible, because then your module can be easier to use (depending on a particular output is all that's required to get the correct ordering) and Terraform will be able to better optimize the actions needed to apply that module.

---

If you already have all of the necessary dependencies declared, including any hidden ones, the problem may instead be outside of what Terraform and the AWS provider is able to see, which can unfortunately make things rather harder to debug.

For example, the `endpoint` attribute from `aws_db_instance` contains a DNS hostname which is established as part of creating the instance, and that DNS record may not be visible to the computer where you are running Terraform immediately after the instance is created.

Any changes involving AWS IAM unfortunately also typically take a few minutes to become visible across all AWS API endpoints, and so if you are using IAM features either to authenticate to the database or have the database authenticate to other systems like S3 then this can cause errors because in most cases AWS offers no way to determine when an IAM change has been fully applied across all services in all regions.

If one of these problems applies to you then unfortunately extra dependency relationships in Terraform will not be sufficient to address it. You might, for example, need to change whatever script you are running to provision the database so that it will be resilient to the database not yet being fully ready and retry a reasonable number of times before failing outright.

Several resource types in the AWS provider already do this sort of polling to work around design quirks of the AWS API, but if you are taking actions outside of the AWS provider itself (in a script run by a provisioner, for example) you must unfortunately take on that responsibility yourself, accepting that cloud computing platforms are complex distributed systems and so they often don't become fully consistent until some time after an API endpoint has returned successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to mark this as it solved the question, but this did fix my problem:
When I had a dependency on the aws_rds_cluster, the cluster finishes provisioning, but the aws_rds_cluster_instance has not finish to provision. I fixed this by having a dependency on the instance as well:

```
module "instance" {
  source = "../instance"
  rds_endpoint    = module.databases.rds_cluster_endpoint
  # This will make the instance module depend on the instance, 
  # which was the one that was not ready yet
  rds_instance_arn    = module.databases.rds_instance_arn
}
```